# Turning a python function into a class without breaking the API

Tags: python, oop

So I created a python library for computing error metrics between time series ([here](https://github.com/BYU-Hydroinformatics/HydroErr)). When I was first creating the library, I was a beginner programmer with pretty much zero previous experience, so for every error metric, I just wrote it as a function. Today, I was thinking it might be nice if each error metric was represented as a class, so a user could do something like the following.

```
# Name of the package
import HydroErr as he

he.r_squared.description  # Would return out a brief metric description
```

I would want to keep the old API syntax intact, or it would break all legacy code. It would have to look something like this when simulated and observed data was passed in.

```
import HydroErr as he
import numpy as np

he.r_squared(np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1.1, 1.21, 1.3]))
# Out: 0.9966777408637874
```

I'm not really sure how to do this, and more importantly if I should do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to turn the functions into classes for this to work:

```
def r_squared(x, y):
    """ Do things... """
    return 56
r_squared.description = r_squared.__doc__
```

You can write a decorator if there's many functions like that:

```
def add_description(fn):
    fn.description = fn.__doc__

@add_description
def r_squared(x, y):
    """ Do things... """
    return 56
```

Comment: Yes, I've attached the docstring to `.description`, but you can put arbitrary values on function attributes.

Comment: So is this possible because functions are essentially represented as objects in python? It's interesting to me that a function can have properties like this

Comment: Yes, functions are objects, just like everything else in Python (at least everything you get to interact with directly). Not all objects support attribute assignment, but functions do, which is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

To turn a function in a class you can use the `__call__` method :

```py
def function(param):
    pass

# Becomes

class MyClass:
    def __call__(self, param):
        pass

    def other_method(self):
        pass

function = MyClass()
```

Both can be used like this : `function(42)`